# Labeled paragraphs

Tags: comments

I would like to be able to label some paragraphs in a document and, when I compile the document using PdfLaTeX, choose which labels I want to keep in my document. More clearly, I would like to define an environment `\begin{labeledparagraph}[label]...\end{labeledparagraph}` (`label` being an argument of `labeledparagraph`) and a function `\selectlabels{label1,label2,label4}` (for example) which I would put in the preamble of my document.

Here is an example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}

\selectlabels{label1,label2,label4}

\begin{document}

\begin{labeledparagraph}[label1]
  Paragraph1
\end{labeledparagraph}

\begin{labeledparagraph}[label2]
  Paragraph2
\end{labeledparagraph}

\begin{labeledparagraph}[label3]
  Paragraph3
\end{labeledparagraph}

\begin{labeledparagraph}[label4]
  Paragraph4
\end{labeledparagraph}

\end{document}
```

When compiling this document, I would like my PDF document to contain only paragraphs 1,2 and 4. The idea is to avoid using only `\begin{comment}...\end{comment}` for each paragraph I want to exclude from the output document.

The `labeledparagraph` environment could be something like this :

```
\newenvironment{labeledparagraph}[1]{\begin{#1}}{\end{#1}}
```

and `\selectlabels{label1,label2,label4}` would be equivalent to

```
\includecomment{label1}
\includecomment{label2}
\excludecomment{label3}
\includecomment{label4}
```

But I don't know how to do it automatically (the number of labels can be quite large). Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please add information if you need the numbering of the paragraphs to stay as in the complete document. Say, you exclude par 3 out of 4. Should 4 still be treated as par 4 or 3? You do know the command `\includeonly`, don't you?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : The numbering of the paragraphs is not important. Yes, I know the `includeonly` command but this is for a document on which several people will be working and they want everything in ONE `.tex` document. This is why I did not consider having one `.tex` file for each paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagging}
\usetag{1,2,4}

\begin{document}
\tagged{1}{
111111111111111111111111

111111111111111111111111

111111111111111111111111
}

\tagged{2}{
222222222222222222222222

222222222222222222222222

222222222222222222222222
}

\tagged{3}{
333333333333333333333333

333333333333333333333333

333333333333333333333333
}

\tagged{4}{
444444444444444444444444

444444444444444444444444

444444444444444444444444
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you may define own commands like `\selectlabels{}` as you like. If you want to use environments as in your MWE, it would be `\begin{taggedblock}{<taglist>}...\end{taggedblock}`.

Comment: Nice !! Thanks !! I feel stupid. I wish I had know about this package before ! Thanks

Comment: you can even input lists of tags. Like this, every coworker can put own tags to each part and you can compile just "jibounet"-tagged stuff. See the doc: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tagging